# Capistrano Permission denied (public key)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, digital-ocean, capistrano

capistrano deployment not working throwing this error

```
 DEBUG [e3e3e3ee3]       git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).

 DEBUG [e3e3e3ee3]       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have added my public key to server, I am also able to ssh in server, and same with bitbucket.

Comment: probably need an update: `gem "net-ssh", ">= 7.0"`